# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que en un ciclo if me permita volver a ingresar datos si es que son erróneos?

Tags: java

//Programa que solicita un numero, si es par se multiplica por 1, en caso contrario se solicita otro numero sin cerrar el programa

```
    int i;
    int mult;
    
    System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
    i = entrada.nextInt();
    
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        mult = i * 1;
        System.out.println("1 X "+ i + " = " +mult);
        
    } else{
        System.out.println("Es un numero impar, por favor ingresa el dato nuevamente");
    }// Hacer que regrese a pedir el número
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas utilizar un ciclo.

```
while(true) { // Se repetira indefinidamente
    System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
    i = entrada.nextInt();

    if(i % 2 == 0){
        mult = i * 1;
        System.out.println("1 X "+ i + " = " +mult);
        break; // Rompes el ciclo
    } else{
        System.out.println("Es un numero impar, por favor ingresa el dato nuevamente");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar un ciclo do-while

Ej.:

```
    do {
       System.out.print("Ingrese un numero: ");
       i = entrada.nextInt();
    
       if(i % 2 == 0){
          mult = i * 1;
          System.out.println("1 X "+ i + " = " +mult);
        
       } else{
            System.out.println("Es un numero impar, por favor ingresa el dato nuevamente");
       }
   } (i % 2 != 0); // Si es impar se repite
```